# Expectation of $A^TXA$ for random $A$ and $X$

Tags: expected-value, random-matrices

Suppose there are two random matrices (distribution unknown), denoted as $A$ and $X$, both in the $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ space. It is known that $\|A\| \leq 1$ (for any $p$-norm) and $E[X]\geq0$. I hope to evaluate the following expectation
$$E[A^TXA]$$
to be in terms of $E[X]$. My first instinct is to break it down into element-wise expression but it is quite messy and difficult to reconstruct the matrix form. Is there any smarter way to do this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Curious, what book do you use for random matrices?

Comment: $A$ and $X$ are independent of each other?

Comment: @Lee May I ask how did you get this conclusion?

Comment: @Penthrite I think it was wrong

Comment: oh yes, maybe this one: $E[A^TXA]=trE[XAA^T]=tr\{E[X]E[AA^T]\}$

Comment: by the way, $A$ and $X$ cannot be both $\in\mathbb{R}^n$, I assume $A\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$

Comment: Sorry my bad, it was meant to be $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ for both $A$ and $X$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\|A\|\le 1$? Is it in an almost sure sense?

Comment: In the entire sample space $\mathcal{S}$ for random matrix $A$, $\forall A \in \mathcal{S}$ we have $ \|{A}\| \leq 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X = [x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_n].$ Then $AX = [\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{1k}x_{k},\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{2k}x_{k},\cdots, \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{nk}x_{k}]$
and so $$X^{t}AX= \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{ik}x_{i}x_{k}$$
and so $$E[X^tAX] = E\left[\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{ik}x_{i}x_{k}\right] = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}E\left[a_{ik}x_{i}x_{k}\right].$$
Since 
$$E(XYZ) = E(XY)\bar{Z} + Cov(XY, Z)$$
for any three $X,Y,Z$ random variables we have that,
$$E[x_{i}x_{k}a_{ik}] = E[x_{i}x_{k}]E[a_{ik}]+Cov(x_ix_k,a_{ik})$$
$$=E[a_{ik}]c_{ki}+Cov(a_{ik},c_{ki}),$$
where $C$ is the covariance matrix of $X.$
So we have that

$$E[X^tAX]  =\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}E[a_{ik}]c_{ki}+Cov(a_{ik},c_{ki}) $$
$$ = \text{Trace}(E[A]C)+\text{Trace}(K)$$
where $K$ is the covariance matrix of with each entry as $\text{Cov}(a_{ij},c_{mn}).$

Comment: From the question, $X$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, not a vector

Comment: I think I got the notation wrong. $X$ stands for $A$

Comment: Both $A$ and $X$ are matrices according to the OP